# how to import csv file to mysql without error

Tags: mysql, sql

hello guys ive been trying to import my csv file to mysql,but i always get this error
[line 1 is the only one successful(click this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Paaoq.png)

and then i tried to import with option csv load data,but the result get absurd like this
[the date not match(click this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikQNn.png)

and this is the csv file structure
[theres 7 column(click this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NFH0.png)

thank you so much,im sorry if my question and my english hard to understand!

Comment: 1) The error message is not MySQL error message (it may be client's tale about MySQL error). 2) While importing the date must have `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYYMMDD` format, not `DD/MM/YYYY` format. Edit your data or use `LOAD DATA INFILE .. SET ..` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify fields in your statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```